# Accessing items separated by -componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: iphone, arrays, parsing, uitableview

I have an array gathered by componentsSeparatedByString: that looks like the following when I use po in the GDB after the array has gone through componentsSeparatedByString:

```
"\n\t\t           <b>Suburb,
</b> BAIRNSDALE",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Address,
</b> 15K NW BAIRNSDALE",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Reference,
</b> MELWOOD/SCHOOL ROAD",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Last Changed,
</b> 09/04/10 05,
29,
00 PM",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Type,
</b> HOME",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Status,
</b> BUILT",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Property Size,
</b> 2.00 HA.",
    "\n\t\t           <b>Residents,
</b> 2",
    "\n\t\t           <b>First Added Date/Time,
</b> 09/04/10 03,
15,
00 PM",
    "\n\t\t\t"
```

Only problem is, I now can't figure out where to go from here. I need to be able to access each of these items (i.e. type, status, property size) separately rather than just calling the entire array (i.e. currentProperty.status). How do I do this?

Also what's with all the n\t\t\t things - how do I get rid of them?

**Update:** For a similar type of feed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423222/problems-extracting-information-from-rss-feed-description-field) - this was for another project, but I never solved it. The string I'm parsing is referred to as "description" in the other project, but is formatted exactly the same way just with different info.

And here's the code using the componentsSeperatedByString

```
NSString *string = [parser currentString];
            NSArray *strings = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"<br>"];
            NSString *myArrayString = [strings description];

            NSString *finalstring = myArrayString;
            NSArray *finalstrings = [finalstring componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
            NSString *finalArrayString = [finalstrings description];

            parser.currentProperty.description = finalArrayString;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things instantly jump out...

First off, the data looks to be markup. There will be a much better way of parsing this. Could you post the markup you're trying to parse, and also the state the string you're passing into componentsSeparatedByString:

As for the \n\t\t... etc, these are formmating characters... \n is a new line, for example. You'll get rid of them by adopting a better approach to parsing the data.

Comment: OK I previously had a similar problem - have added a link to the information above which is almost exactly the same.